# How to use regex to extract groups of question-answer data from html files?

Tags: regex

How can I use a regular expression to extract groups of html that will be formatted like this:

.

```
.
    .irrelevant html...
    <b>Question 6</b><br>

lots of text
<p>

lots of text
<p>
<br>

<b>Answer 6</b><br>
lots of text 
<p>

lots of text 
<p>

lots of text 
<p>

more text
<p>
<HR>

<IMG SRC="/images/image.jpg" alt="alt text" width=480 height=360 hspace=2 vspace=2> 
<p>

<i>caption text</i>
```

There can be a variable amount of Question-Answer pairs.  And the image code can be anywhere (either between Question and Answer, or after the answer)...

The only info I want to extract is the Question #, the text sans paragraph html code, the Img src and alt and caption.

Comment: Is there a particular language/environment you'd be doing this with?

Also, is it a one-off task against a specific file, or something that will be done regularly, and how consistent might the input be?

Comment: Hi Peter, this is a one off task and is completed :)  There are 350-400 pages all of a very similar format and my parser works on 95% of them.  And I have also developed a separate similar parser for other groups of hundreds of similar pages.  Mission accomplished.

Comment: Hi Gordon, could you post the parser you used as an answer, for the benefit of future readers of this question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at some of the options from this question "[Is there an Application to Create Regular Expression Out of Text by Selecting Wanted Area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122402/is-there-an-application-to-create-regular-expression-out-of-text-by-selecting-w)"

[ReguLazy](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/pages/tools-and-frameworks-by-roy-osherove.aspx) looks like a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using something like Watir. You can then programatically search through the dom and find what you need.